# Can I use NDCG as a loss function in Tensorflow recommender?

Tags: tensorflow, recommender-system

I am trying to follow the sample code here to build a dcn model.

I want to use ndcg as the loss function and metrics,  but the default one here is rmse. [https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/dcn#:~:text=%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20self.task%20%3D%20tfrs.tasks.Ranking(%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20loss%3Dtf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()%2C%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20metrics%3D%5Btf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(%22RMSE%22)%5D%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20)](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/dcn#:%7E:text=%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20self.task%20%3D%20tfrs.tasks.Ranking(%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20loss%3Dtf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()%2C%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20metrics%3D%5Btf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(%22RMSE%22)%5D%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20))

I tried to modify as following, but it won't work.

```
self.task = tfrs.tasks.Ranking(
            loss=tfr.keras.losses.ApproxNDCGLoss(),
            metrics=[tfr.keras.metrics.DCGMetric()]
            )
```

Could someone please guide me through here?